# one git command to show status of all files in a directory

Tags: git

`git ls-files -v -o` # shows untracked files

`git ls-files -v` # shows tracked files

There must be an easier way to show me the status of ALL files in current directory. If there are 259 (possibly hidden) files then I want to see 259 lines, each with a status like

- **matching-HEAD**
- behind-HEAD
- modified
- untracked
- gitignored
- staged
- ...

Conceptually, the ideal command is designed based on the `ls` or `dir` commands, decorated with the git-related file info.

I tried git-status but don't think git-status would show all 259 files. In a typical situation, most of the 259 files would be matching HEAD i.e. no difference from HEAD. I wish git-status could show them.

What I can think of is a script to loop over each file in the directory, work out the git-related status, then print it.

Comment: git status /folder/path/route

Answer (score 1):

The closest match I ever used was:

```
git ls-files -cdmot <PATH_TO_DIR>
```

From the manual:

```
   -c, --cached
       Show cached files in the output (default)

   -d, --deleted
       Show deleted files in the output

   -m, --modified
       Show modified files in the output

   -o, --others
       Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
```

And:

```
   -t
       This feature is semi-deprecated. For scripting purpose, git-status(1) --porcelain
       and git-diff-files(1) --name-status are almost always superior alternatives, and
       users should look at git-status(1) --short or git-diff(1) --name-status for more
       user-friendly alternatives.

       This option identifies the file status with the following tags (followed by a
       space) at the start of each line:
   H
       cached

   S
       skip-worktree

   M
       unmerged

   R
       removed/deleted

   C
       modified/changed

   K
       to be killed

   ?
       other
```

As you've seen, `-t` is marked as *semi-deprecated* in the manual for the version of Git I use (2.17.1). None of the suggested replacements seem to fit exactly the same need, though.

Answer (score -4):

Just run a `git status`. If you want to see more options of what can be done `man git-status`.